# Why won't my page display unless I put an .html at the end of URL?

Tags: html, database, invoice

For some reason after transferring to a new server my invoices page and script aren't working. When a customer enters his information it is put in the database and it creates an invoice like so:

/Invoices/JohnDoe 10100188

However the URL should open up a nice invoice page with all the info for the order, instead I get a 404 Error now. Nothing has changed with the script or databases. We simply moved them to a new server and all the included files.  What's even stranger is that when you add .html to the end of JohnDoe 10100188 it will load the page. I don't know why but do I need to make my script add .html at the end now? It is confusing to me why this won't work now.. I was hoping someone had a similar problem and could help me out. I would be greatly appreciative!

Comment: I think you should specify how such invoice pages are generated, the server-side language used, the previous/current server software (IIS, Apache, ...), other particular configurations (e.g. strange `.htaccess` used), ...

Comment: My educated guess is that you don't have a physical file on disc for every single invoice you've ever created. Instead, you are using a server side tool (for instance, Apache's mod_rewrite) so your URL gets mapped to a script that retrieves the appropriate information for the database and composes an HTML document on the fly.

In general, you cannot migrate applications blindly. You need to know the technical requirements of the server: what OS, server side language and optional modules/extensions are required.

Comment: I have a folder called Invoices where the physical file is created and stored. We have thousands and they add every time someone orders. The server tech says there is nothing wrong on their end but he also said Apache is having an error: These are the errors being generated in /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log whenever the view invoice link is clicked:

[Mon Jan 03 10:08:42 2011] [error] [client 24.30.32.138] File does not exist: /home/cody1/public_html/Invoices/PeterTims03011121713, referer: http://www.hidcountry.com/orders2.php?type=ordered&submit=View_Date&year3=11&month3=01&day3=03

Comment: Sorry guys I'm not entirely new to this stuff because I used it in college but that was years ago. I'm the director of marketing so I do mostly graphics, ads and other marketing including the website. However, we needed a new server so we moved and boom, errors...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Apache, but my guess would be that there's a configuration setting where you can set a default file extension for the case when one is not supplied.

Could be in .htaccess, or one of the Apache config files.